# Meteor : Update an element in a specified array index in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

So I'm coming from a pure javascript background and I'm working on a meteor project on which I have the following MongoDB collection, named "Semaines":

```
{
    _id: /*random ID*/,
    id_utilisateur: /*user ID*/,
    isCreated: true,
    jours: {
        lundi: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        mardi: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        mercredi: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        jeudi: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        vendredi: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        samedi: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        dimanche: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    }
}
```

Using the following method, I want to update the element at the specified day and index (here representing hours):

```
    //sent values are : idUt = Meteor.userId(), day = "vendredi", hour = 0, score = 10
    'semaines.updateTable'(idUt, day, hour, score){
        check(idUt, String);
        check(day, String);
        check(hour, Number);
        check(score, Number);
        Semaines.update({id_utilisateur: idUt},{$set : {"jours.$[day].$[hour]": score}});
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work. I think it's because the query actually is, with the values I'm sending:

```
    $set : {jours.vendredi.0 : 10}
```

This obviously will not work, but I fail to see how my query can become this, which I assume would work:

```
    $set : {jours.vendredi[0] : 10}
```

Comment: Can you please add the current **complete** structure of the document to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution for Meteor > 1.6.2 / Mongo > 3.6 - Use an arrayFilter:

What you want to do is use [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in your query (`{[keyVar]: val}`), and nest it.

You will also need to use an [arrayFilter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to target the specific index of the array

```
Semaines.update(
  { id_utilisateur: idUt },
  { $set : { jours: { [day]: { "$[index]": score } } } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { index: hour } ] },
);
```

Because it is currently this literal string: `"jours.$[day].$[hour]"`

I'm not sure if Meteor Collections pass through options like this though so you may need to get the raw mongo collection:

```
Semaines.rawCollection().update(
  { id_utilisateur: idUt },
  { $set : { jours: { [day]: { "$[index]": score } } } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { index: hour } ] },
);
```

---

### Solution for Meteor < 1.6.2 / Mongo < 3.6 - Replace the array

Without access to the more powerful operators in Mongo 3.6, we're left to do the work ourselves in javascript:

```
'semaines.updateTable'(idUt, day, hour, score){
    check(idUt, String);
    check(day, String);
    check(hour, Number);
    check(score, Number);
    const doc = Semaines.findOne({ id_utilisateur: idUt });
    const array = doc.jours[day];
    array[hour] = score;
    Semaines.update(
        { id_utilisateur: idUt },
        // Replace the entire jours object with a clone and modify day
        { $set : { jours: { ...doc.jours, [day]: array } } },
    );
}
```

---

Note: While Mongo 3.4 has a `$position` option for `$push`, it doesn't have it for `$pull`, so we can't just replace the element in-place

Comment: I don't know if I need to modify anything to your code, but straight-up copy/paste returns this error.

"Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'semaines.updateTable' errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 409, reason: "MinimongoError: Key $[index] must not start with '$'", details: undefined, message: "MinimongoError: Key $[index] must not start with '$' [409]", …} Error: MinimongoError: Key $[index] must not start with '$' [409]"

Comment: I'll spin up a meteor app and take a look

Comment: I missed the part in the docs which says the `"$[foo]":` syntax is new in version 3.6. Which isn't coming till Meteor 1.6.2

Comment: Edited answer to include solution with current Meteor+Mongo versions

Comment: It almost works perfectly: now it deletes the other "lundi", "mardi" etc. arrays, but a fix I found was to simply delete the "jours" object containing the seven arrays. Now it works, thanks !
Any idea why it would behave as such ?

Comment: Oh because it's setting `jours` to be the new object. try with: `{ $set : { [`jours.${day}`]: array } }` for the nested string selector, or `{ $set : { jours: { ...doc.jours, [day]: array } } }` to replace the whole `jours` object with everything that was already there. We should edit in the one that works